# Стилизация элемента до определенного класса

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть возможность выставления звездного рейтинга, при клике добавляется класс `active` ,который окрашивает звездочку(ну и всякие ненужные в этой теме штуки). Нужно чтобы окрашивались звездочки указанные до  класса `active` включительно. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rait(r) {
  clear()
  for (var i = 1; i < r + 1; i++) {
    var star = document.getElementsByClassName("star-" + i)
    star[0].className = "star-" + i + " active"
  }
}

function clear() {
  for (var e = 1; e <= 5; e++) {
    var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("star-" + e)
    stars[0].className = "star-" + e
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="rait(1)" class="star-1">★</a>
<a onclick="rait(2)" class="star-2">★</a>
<a onclick="rait(3)" class="star-3">★</a>
<a onclick="rait(4)" class="star-4">★</a>
<a onclick="rait(5)" class="star-5">★</a>
```

Comment: Если выбрать вначале 5 звездочек, а потом выбрать меньше, то меньше в вашем примере не выбирается. Но при этом если выбрать 3 звездочки, то вполне можно потом выбрать 4 или 5. Тоесть больше можно, а меньше нельзя.

Comment: @Vladimir Medinsky, ну так, добавьте отчистку звезд до цикла `for` и все будет работать.

Comment: @And ,  я к тому и веду что тут этого не хватает

Comment: @Vladimir Medinsky, то есть, опять-же, нужно сделать за вас:))

Comment: @And , не я автор темы, мой ответ в теме ниже если что, и не для меня нужно это сделать и не за меня :)

Answer (score 1):

Средствами css нельзя стилизовать элементы "до", но можно "после".

```js
$('.star').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.star {
  color:yellow;
  text-decoration:none
}
.active ~ .star{
  color:gray;
}

body {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="star active">★</a>
<a href="#" class="star">★</a>
<a href="#" class="star">★</a>
<a href="#" class="star">★</a>
<a href="#" class="star">★</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на css (`display: flex + flex-direction: row-reverse;`)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.rating input {
  display: none;
}
.rating [for*=star]{
  font-size: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.rating [for*=star]:before {
  content: '★ ';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.rating input:checked~[for*=star] {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="star5">5 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4">
  <label for="star4">4 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
  <label for="star3">3 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
  <label for="star2">2 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
  <label for="star1">1 star</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не ограничены в использовании JavaScript (JQuery), то можно, получив элемент, по которому кликнули, взять из него класс стилей, напимер star-4, взять это название и получить последний символ (ведь число звездочек ограничего 5 ? тогда хватит последнего символа) и далее циклом добавить класс active ко всем star-N до 4.

```js
$('[class^=star]').click(function(e) {
  let classList = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
      if (item.indexOf('star')>=0) {
          makeActiveStars(Number.parseInt(item[item.length - 1]));
      }
  });
});

function makeActiveStars(count) {
   for (let i=0; i<=5; ++i) {
      if (i<=count) {
        $('.star-' + i).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $('.star-' + i).removeClass('active');
      }
   }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f69c55;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="star-1 cursor-pointer">★</a>
<a class="star-2 cursor-pointer">★</a>
<a class="star-3 cursor-pointer">★</a>
<a class="star-4 cursor-pointer">★</a>
<a class="star-5 cursor-pointer">★</a>
```

Comment: `$('[class^=star').click(function(e)` тут опечатка ? Недостает квадратной скобки? Не работает что-то.

Comment: опечатку исправил, но код работает, попробуйте нажать ctrl+f5 на этой странице и запустить ещё раз по кнопке "Выполнить код"

Answer (score -1):

```js
function rating(e) {
 e.addEventListener("click", el => {
  let child = e.lastElementChild, active = false;
  while(child) {
   if (child === el.target) { active = true }
   child.classList[active ? "add" : "remove"]("active");
   child = child.previousElementSibling;
  }
 });
}

rating(document.querySelector(".rating"))
```

```css
.rating {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0px;
 cursor: default;
 font-size: 0px;
 user-select: none;
}

.rating > li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.rating > li::before {
  content: "★"
}

.rating > li.active,
.rating > li:hover {
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```